# Geoserver 2.14+ fails on Glassfish4+ - Anyone succeeded with this?

Tags: glassfish, geoserver

During hardware migration, thought it sensible to upgrade Geoserver from 2.13.0 to 2.14.2 on Glassfish 4.0 hoping to cure flakiness.

JVM is configured to use a non-standard data directory using JVM parameter:
-DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/geoserver

Using the .war downloaded from Geoserver.org, deployment fails

2.15.x exhibits the same failure
2.13.0 deploys and runs, albeit with some flakiness (similar stack track shown on the home-page of geoserver once logged in)

The issue appears platform independent, environments used:

Windows 10 X64 running Oracle Java 1.8.0_161 on Glassfish 4 OR Glassfish 5 (including fresh out-of box installs of Glassfish)

CentOS 7 running OpenJDK 1.8.0_222 on Glassfish 4

The WAR did deploy on a localhost (W10) install of TomCat, albeit without the custom data directory set

If latest GeoServer builds could be made to work on Glassfish 4, this would save considerable time and expense

Any suggestions appreciated

```
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcFacade' defined in URL [jar:file:/E:/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.14.5.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.gwc.GWC]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /geoserver
Warning:   The web application [/geoserver] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Severe:   The web application [/geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal.SuppliedThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal@e524836]) and a value of type [org.geowebcache.storage.CompositeBlobStore.StoreSuitabilityCheck] (value [EXISTING]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcFacade' defined in URL [jar:file:/E:/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.14.5.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.gwc.GWC]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Comment: you are probably going to have to pay a [commercial support](http://geoserver.org/support/) company to work on Glassfish - as far as I know none of the regular developers even thinks about using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing this is because the application you are trying to deploy packages a different Google Guava version than the one that Glassfish ships with. Unfortunately Glassfish favours its own packaged version which does not have the method `com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;)`.

There exist some (more or less involved) workarounds.
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/20850

Since you seem to have a WAR archive, this comment https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/20850#issuecomment-422010251 suggests that it might be enough to disable the classloader delegation in the `glassfish-web.xml`. Maybe you are lucky and this is indeed helping with your WAR file.
Otherwise you'll have to switch to Payara which seems to have this bug fixed since some time.

Comment: Adding a glassfish-web.xml file to WEB-INF in the WAR file where classloader delegation is disabled appears to work, at the very least for getting Geoserver deployed. I haven't tested it more thoroughly yet, but this does appear to be the solution.

This is sufficiently simple a fix that i'd highly reccommend anyone involved with the Geoserver project add notes to their pages to inform others still slumming it with the reference implementation of Glassfish!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @ChristophJohn Now awarded the bounty, sorry for the delay, never done one before and didn't realise I had to manually award it.